# How to reset `CMMontionManager`'s `attitude`

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion, device-orientation, cmmotionmanager

I want to reset `CMMotionManager`'s `attitude` so the `rotationMatrix` points to the "front" (that is, the device rotation around the gravity axis it's at its default position). This is the behavior when you call `-startDeviceMotionUpdates` on a disabled `CMMotionManager`.

Once the motion manager it's running, if you call `-stopDeviceMotionUpdates`, wait for a while, and then you call `-startDeviceMotionUpdates` again, I get the behavior I'm looking for.

However, the `attitude` is not reset if you call `-stopDeviceMotionUpdates` and immediately call `-startDeviceMotionUpdates` again; it keeps the previous attitude. Instantiating a new `CMMotionManager` produces the same results (I guess the motion manager system is a singleton under the hoods).

Is there a way I make sure that *iOS's motion manager* internal `attitude` is reset without introducing artificial or arbitrary delays

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: I didn’t, sorry.